# Error building Player: Vuforia Engine does not support Android TV

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

When building an AR project for Android using Unity3D and Vuforia I'm getting the following error:

> Error building Player: Vuforia Engine does not support Android TV.
>   Please disable the Android TV compatibility in the Player Settings.

How can I solve it and build the .apk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error basically gives the solution. By default Unity checks the box "Android TV Compatibility". One has to go to File > Project Settings > Player and under *Other Settings* we can uncheck it.

[image: Android TV Compatibility]

Answer (score 1):

SOLUTION:

Unity project ->Edit -> Player Settings -> Other Settings -> Disable the Android TV Compatibility